# Mass assignment error in polymorphic favourite model setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec, polymorphic-associations, mass-assignment

I am trying to adding favouriting to my app so that users can select favourite projects.

I have tried to use the code that I found here: http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/588-How-to-implement-favorites-in-Rails-with-polymorphic-associations

Here's my current situation:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :favourites
  has_many :favourite_projects, :through =>  :favourites, :source => :favourable, :source_type => "Project"
end
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
  has_many :favourites, :as => :favourable
  has_many :fans, :through => :favourites, :source => :user
end
```

**task.rb**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

**favourite.rb**

```
class Favourite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favourable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :user, :favourable
end
```

**favourite_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Favourite do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:project) { FactoryGirl.create(:project_with_task) }
  let(:favourite_project) do
    user.favourite_projects.build(favourable: project.id)
  end

  subject { favourite_project }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "accessible attributes" do
    it "should not allow access to user_id" do
      expect do
        Favourite.new(user_id: user.id)
      end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end
  end

end
```

When I run the test though, the user_id test passes but I get the following for `it { should be_valid }`:

```
Failure/Error: user.favourite_projects.build(favourable: project.id)
     ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
       Can't mass-assign protected attributes: favourable
```

Am I doing something wrong in my test?

Or the way I am calling `.build`?

Or in the `attr_accessible` on the Favourite model?

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Here's the files that had to be changed from those shown in the question:

**favourites.rb**

```
class Favourite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favourable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :favourable
end
```

**favourite_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Favourite do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:project) { FactoryGirl.create(:project_with_task) }
  let(:favourite_project) do
    user.favourites.build(favourable: project)
  end

  subject { favourite_project }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "accessible attributes" do
    it "should not allow access to user_id" do
      expect do
        Favourite.new(user_id: user.id)
      end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end
    it "should not allow access to user" do
      expect do
        Favourite.new(user: user)
      end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end
  end

end
```